# How do I run Ubuntu Server headless using Parallels Desktop?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, parallels

Running VMs "headless" (without windows for each VM being visible on the host) is a great feature of VirtualBox. How do I do it using Parallels Desktop on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure Parallels Desktop is **not** running. If it is running, the commands below will still create a console window.

From Terminal.app, use the Parallels command line: `prlctl`

```sh
# List available VMs
prlctl list --all

# Start a VM using its name
prlctl start UbuntuServer

# Stop the VM
prlctl stop UbuntuServer

# Pause and Resume
prlctl pause UbuntuServer
prlctl resume UbuntuServer

# Reset and Restart
prlctl reset UbuntuServer
prlctl restart UbuntuServer
```

Comment: What makes this require Parallels Desktop to be closed?  Can headless machines not be run along side (in parallel if you will) to ones with a monitor attached?

Comment: `The command is available only in Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro or Business Edition.`

Answer (score 38):

rutgerw's answer does work, but doesn't work well if you need to run alongside virtual machines for which you need to use the GUI.  Try this command in Terminal...

```
prlctl set UbuntuServer --on-window-close keep-running
```

Now if you close the UbuntuServer window it will continue to run in the background.  Parallels doesn't support true "headless" mode, but this gets you pretty close.

Further Reading:
[Parallels prlctl Reference](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Command_Line_Reference_Guide/23465.htm)

If you are a Parallels Desktop Enterprise user, you can run a VM as a background service.  This is an enterprise-only feature. See the [documentation](http://kb.parallels.com/121317).

Comment: Thanks!  I've been hiding the console window this whole time.

Comment: I'll get back with more details once I've gotten around to upgrading, but apparently Parallels Desktop 10 supports true headless mode (according to the features list).

Comment: Added some info for Parallels Desktop Enterprise users.

Comment: `The command is available only in Parallels Desktop for Mac Pro or Business Edition.`

Comment: That's new then. This worked when I last needed it in Parallels 7. I'm aware that's a bit dated now.

Answer (score 7):

Although the question is old, it is the second hit on google searching for headless mode.

Parallels Desktop 16 for Mac has such an option.
Open the preferences for the VM and choose the following option:

[image]

(sry, german version, but you'll find it )

Comment: As of 2022, this should be the correct answer.

Comment: There is no headless in Parallels Desktop 18 standard edition ? :/